# My textbox displaying data from serial port is updating too slow

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I'm making a C# Win forms app that reads data from an arduino over serial port, parses it and displays it in a textbox.

My problem is that the value in the textbox is always a few seconds older than the value being sent by arduino even if I slow down the arduino to send the data once per second.

I know the problem must be in my C# code because when I read the serial port using a serial monitor everything's fine.

my code:

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string msgType;
    string serialMsg;
    serialMsg = port.ReadLine();

    if(serialMsg.Substring(0, 1) != "#")
    {
        return;
    }

    msgType = serialMsg.Substring(1, 4);

    if(msgType == "VOLT") // recieve supply voltage reading
    {
        textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { textBox1.Text = serialMsg.Substring(5, serialMsg.Length - 5); });
    }
    if (msgType == "AMPS") // recieve supply current reading
    {
        textBox2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { textBox2.Text = serialMsg.Substring(5, serialMsg.Length - 5); });
    }
    if (msgType == "LOAD") // recieve load current reading
    {
        textBox3.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { textBox3.Text = serialMsg.Substring(5, serialMsg.Length - 5); });
    }
}
```

The messages coming from the arduino are in this format: `# + TYPE + DATA`

Can you tell me what's slowing it down?

Comment: It's odd to have `serialMsg = port.ReadLine();` inside an event handler method, and the event object `e` is not being used at all.

Comment: How was the timing when you used `//Console.WriteLine("amps");` ? instead of the textboxes?

Comment: @Loathing " and the event object e is not being used at all" how would you use it?

Comment: "The messages coming from the arduino are in this format: # + TYPE + DATA" is there a `"\r\n"` at the end of every Arduino message? because you use `ReadLine` (which is blocking) and will wait until it finds a newline in the received message.

Comment: @MongZhu Usually when a specific class is created for an event object then it will contain additional properties that contain the needed information to respond to the event. I don't know which properties the `SerialDataReceivedEventArgs` contains, but was pointing out it was strange that it wasn't used in his code.

Comment: @Loathing ok, I get it. Actually this object is quite useless in a lot of cases of serial port communication. At least that is my personal experience. It has this [strange enum value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialdata?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) which tells you a "bit/char" of information ;)

Comment: @MongZhu I looked it up, and it indeed seems like an empty class, so nothing useful. The example given on the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) page is the same format.

Comment: @MongZhu yes the message is terminated by \r

Comment: can you post also the arduino code? my guess would be that the newline character is not always sent. " yes the message is terminated by \r" always? actually this shouldn't be enough. Try using `ReadExisting()` and see whether the timing changes

Comment: @MongZhu When I just print to the console when I get the message it's fast as it should be

Comment: Then try this: `textBox2.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => textBox2.Text = serialMsg.Substring(5, serialMsg.Length - 5));`

Comment: @VojtaDegeš Do all the console output lines start with `#` ?

Comment: @MongZhu I tried to output the actual parsed data into the console instead of just Console.WriteLine("amps"); and it caused the same problem as with the textbox. I also tried to send only the VOLT message instead of all three of them and it solved all the lagging. I'll try to use ReadExisting to see what that does.

Comment: @VojtaDegeš Also, in general `BeginInvoke` shouldn't be called more than ever 100 milliseconds apart because it's an expensive call. So it could be that. If that is the case, then aggregate your messages, or skip some, and then only call `BeginInvoke`, much less frequently.

Comment: @VojtaDegeš Just FYI, you should be using `BeginInvoke` and not `Invoke`.

Comment: @VojtaDegeš: Try showing the data from serial port right after `serialMsg = port.ReadLine();`. Maybe all the next operations are taking a long time and causing the lagging. Then if it causes some difference then try doing the operations after the data is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was sending the messages from the arduino too quickly so I put a 50ms delay between them
I also used ReadExisting instead of ReadLine

This solved all the lagging

Comment: "I was sending the messages from the arduino too quickly so I put a 50ms delay". This high update rate is not really adequate for a gui display. Think about it, even if the gui would be able to handle all this data, do you expect a human observer to notice that a value has changed **200 times** in only **1** second?

Comment: You should really not be doing all your parsing, calculations, and gui in the data received event as that is where you are reading all the data.  Putting a delay in the Arduino is just a band aid to the issue at hand.  The PC has no issue receiving data that quickly, the issue is you're doing too much in your data received event.  A better solution would be to have a queue in which you put your data received string into and have a background worker popping the queue in which you do all your work in there.

Comment: @VojtaDeges: Please accept your answer if it works for you.